# XPATH DomDocument retrieivng first node of div elements

Tags: php, dom, xpath

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="post">
        <img class="img" src="getme"/> (<~~ retrieve this one)
        <img class="img" src="notme"/>
        <img class="img" src="notme"/>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <img class="img" src="getme"/> (<~~ retrieve this one)
        <img class="img" src="notme"/>
        <img class="img" src="notme"/>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Here is the XPATH's I've used:

```
     //div[@class="content"]//div[@class="post"]//@src[1]
     (//div[@class="content"]//div[@class="post"]//@src)[1]
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is retrieving only the ones I explicitly stated as to retrieve. When I use the second Xpath (`(//div[@class="content"]//div[@class="post"]//@src)[1]`) one it only provides the first img src and thats it (not the first one for every div post element)

Answer (score 2):

Use the following xpath query:

```
//div[@class="post"]/img[1]/@src
```

Example:

```
$html = <<<EOF
<div class="content">
    <div class="post">
        <img class="img" src="getme"/> (<~~ retrieve this one)
        <img class="img" src="notme"/>
        <img class="img" src="notme"/>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <img class="img" src="getme"/> (<~~ retrieve this one)
        <img class="img" src="notme"/>
        <img class="img" src="notme"/>
    </div>    
</div>
EOF;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach($selector->query('//div[@class="post"]/img[1]/@src') as $node) {
    var_dump($node->nodeValue);
}
```

Output:

```
string(5) "getme"
string(5) "getme"
```